# Lexical collocation of "former"

Tags: word-choice, word-usage, collocation

[image: the former president]

Imagine that you are the president of a company, and there was another person playing the same role before you.

How should I describe the former president using the expression like "He was the former president *** you"?

Question

1. I believe "of" can be chosen.  Is this correct?
2. When "of" is correctly used, how about the sentence "He was the former president of **yours**"?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You just wouldn't say it that way in English. You'd say more easily something like. 'The president before you', or 'your preceding president'. The former president before you' is a jarring pleonasm.

Comment: "He was your predecessor"

Comment: 'Former' relates to ordinal but not interval information: 'immediately preceding' is fine, but not 'immediately former'.

Answer (score 1):

"He was the former president of you [or *yours*]" doesn't work at all to convey the meaning "He was the president immediately before you [and you are currently the president]." In fact, "He was the former president of you" has two major problems. First it is overdefined, since you can convey the sense of the sentence less confusingly by dropping the word *former* from it:

> He was the president of you.

Second, the meaning that the sentence conveys—that he formerly was **your** president—appears not to be what you intend to say. Rather, you seem to want to express something along the lines of

> He was [the] president of the company before you.

That simple wording is fine, if its general meaning is what you have in mind. But this wording does not expressly indicate that the former president was the president you succeeded. Similarly, we could say "James Monroe [the fifth U.S. President] was President of the United States before John Tyler [the tenth U.S. President]," but obviously Monroe wasn't Tyler's immediate predecessor.

As Mitch suggests in a comment above, referring to someone as "the former president before you" would imply that you, too, are a former president. If you are currently serving as president, saying that person X "was the president before you" amply indicates that person X is no longer president but was your immediate predecessor in the office. Using "was the president before you" establishes that person X is no longer the president.

As StoneyB notes in another comment above, a very simple way to identify person X as your predecessor in office is to say "He was your predecessor as president." To underscore the fact that person X was the most recent president before you, I would add *immediate* to the sentence:

> "He was your immediate predecessor as president."

Answer (score 1):

Why not **past president**?

See: http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/past-president

Sven's sentence: "He was your immediate predecessor as president." 
becomes: He is the immediate past president.